# King of Tokyo card question+ dice read

Tags: king-of-tokyo

1. Jets says

> You suffer no damage when yielding Tokyo.

If the monster in Tokyo has 3 health and he should receive 3 attacks, he should die or he can just leave Tokyo?

2. In 5 players game Gigazour is in Tokyo, Tokyo Bay is free and CyberBunny 8 health rolled 2 heal and 3 attack (Gigazour doesnt't want to leave Tokyo). So CyberBunny can recover 2 heal, then 
   hits 3 times Gigazour and then go to Tokyo Bay, right?

Comment: In general, if you have two questions like this, it is better to ask them separately.  That way people can answer and vote on each one individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, that's basically the point of the card.  Here's a [BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/742381/jets-card) confirming it.
2. CyberBunny is not currently in Tokyo, so he is definitely able to heal.  And since he is not in Tokyo, the damage he deals is applied to monsters in Tokyo.  Since Gigazour does not leave Tokyo, CyberBunny is placed in Tokyo Bay.  So yes, your resolution is correct.